# How to remove the outline for the cell in table when you click the cell?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to remove all the outline effects when I click the cell. I inspected the element but failed to find which class name should I give border:none style.
Thanks for the help!
https://codesandbox.io/s/datatable-material-demo-forked-mo715?file=/demo.js

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader:focus,
.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

Add this to your styles/css.